# TypeError: 'null' is not an object

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

This is my Prototype / JS code:

```
if($('myElemId')) {
    myVar = $('myElemId').checked;
}
```

This is the error I get in Safari: *TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$('myElemId').checked')*

Why is that and why is it only coming up in Safari? Do I get it right that the selector returns null and thus the checked state cant be fetched?

Comment: I think in Prototype you select an element by ID using $('id').

Comment: @tymeJV: He's using [`$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/), not jQuery!!!

Comment: @Bergi -- Well now I feel like an idiot! Nice catch

Comment: It's not enough info in this question so far. Could you share some more details? HTML layout, scripts you load?

Comment: Well, what else can I say? It works in all other grade A browsers, only Safari has a problem here. The elment is loaded when that JS runs, so its there.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you cache the result of lookup? Like `var $elem = $('myElemId'); if ($elem) { myVar = $elem.checked; }`? That's actually the most confusing part for me: how come the same lookup obviously done in the same thread returns different results?

Comment: BTW, which version of Safari/Prototype.js are we talking about? )

Comment: What does `console.log($('myElemId'));` show?

Comment: change `if($('myElemId'))` to `if($('myElemId') != undefined)` Prototype's `$()` returns null/undefined if an element with that id does not exist on the page/in the DOM

Comment: did you ever figure this out?